# What's the correct way to use django's ModelFormMixin?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I've read through the docs on this and yet I can't seem to get django's ModelFormMixin working properly. This is what I have in urls.py:

```
...
url(r'^vendors/edit/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', 'vendor_edit', name='vendor_edit'),
...
```

and in views.py:

```
class VendorEditView(DetailView, ModelFormMixin):
    form_class = VendorForm
    model = Vendor
    success_url = reverse_lazy('vendor_list')
    template_name = 'vendor_edit.html'
```

and the template:

```
<form action='.' method='post'>{% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
    <button>Save</button>
</form>
```

I've tried mixing it into different types of views besides `DetailView` (`View`, `TemplateView`, `FormView`) with no luck.

What I expect to happen is that when I go to `/vendors/edit/1`, a form is on the page with the object's details already filled in for editing. What I'm getting is either a blank form, no form, or a 405 HTTP response. Is there something obvious I'm missing here?

Comment: Can you please share the content of your template file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out: Needed to use django's `UpdateView` with the mixin to get it working.

Edit: Per comments, no need to mix it in to the `UpdateView`, as it's already included in the inheritance chain.

Comment: You don't need to use the mixin, it's already a parent class of `UpdateView`

Comment: @AndrewIngram Ah, seems like you're right. I normally love the django docs but found them to be very confusing here :-/ (and I've been using it for years!)